# Strange java behavior of wait/notify

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I've found strange behavior of java concurrency. See on the next code below:

```
public class Test {
    static CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, InterruptedException {
        final Thread t = new MyThread();
        t.start();
        synchronized (t) {
            latch.countDown();
            System.out.println("got to sleep");
            t.wait();
            System.out.println("wake up");
        }
    }

    static class MyThread extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                latch.await();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            synchronized (this) {
                System.out.println("inside run");
//                notifyAll();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my point of view this code should be hang up and wait forever, but code is finished without any problem with next out in console:

```
got to sleep
inside run
wake up
```

I've tried to find some information about notifying locks if thread is died, but was lack in it.
Also I've not find any information in java specification.

But if I've tried to lock on some other object (not on the thread object) it was work fine as I expected.

Comment: You lock on the sync on the thread instance, run the thread, then wait on the thread in Main.  At this point, the thread should have the reigns.  It syncs on the this, which is the same thing Main waited on, then calls notifyAll(), which releases the wait in Main.  The app should run fine.

Comment: Additionally, do *not* call wait/notify/notifyAll on Thread - it uses it internally. Oh, and prefer implementing Runnable instead of extending Thread :)

Comment: why is notifyAll() commented out? If it is active then I would also expect the code not to hang up.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's because you're waiting on a `Thread` instance. `Thread` uses `wait`/`notify`/`notifyAll` internally, so you shouldn't do that yourself as well - you'll confuse `Thread`, and `Thread` will confuse you. In particular, when a thread exits, it calls `this.notifyAll()`.

From the documentation of `Thread.join`:

> This implementation uses a loop of `this.wait` calls conditioned on `this.isAlive`. As a thread terminates the `this.notifyAll` method is invoked. It is recommended that applications not use `wait`, `notify`, or `notifyAll` on `Thread` instances.

In general, try to lock and wait for objects which *nothing* else can interact with. That way you can reason about the concurrency-related operations which exist on the object, because they're very limited. As soon as arbitrary code can synchronize on the object (and call wait/notify etc) it's hard to prove that your code is correct. That's why you'll often see something like:

```
public class Foo {
    private final Object lock = new Object();

    ... code which uses synchronized(lock) ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I know that it's bad practice. It's just like java puzzle. My friend asked about this problem and I couldn't explain why it's not work.

Comment: @EvgeniyKiselev: Well, hopefully now you can :) In future, I would add some indication of the context to the question. Not a big problem in this case, but it would generally be helpful.

Comment: This could happen even if it wasn't a thread instance since spurious wakeups are permitted.

Answer (score 0):

As Jon Skeet writes it is bad idea to synchronize on Thread object, use another one:

```
public class Test {
    static CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    static final Object sync = new Object();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, InterruptedException {
        final Thread t = new MyThread();
        t.start();
        synchronized (sync) {
            latch.countDown();
            System.out.println("got to sleep");
            sync.wait();
            System.out.println("wake up");
        }
    }
}

static class MyThread extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            latch.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        synchronized (sync) {
            System.out.println("inside run");
            //sync.notifyAll();
        }
    }
}
```

Now this code will never ending until you uncomment sync.notifyAll();

Comment: I know that it's bad practice and I know that if locks on different object, it will works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It is behaving differently due to the lock is taken on the Thread instance, if you will lock on the different object (or maybe Object obj) then it will work fine i.e `wake up` will not be printed and the main thread would wait.